# Flutter - Quiz app, button with correct answer should be showing green

Tags: function, flutter, if-statement, dart

I am building a quiz app in flutter and each time the user selects a wrong answer I would like the correct answer (button) to turn green colour.

These are my variables

```
Color colorToShow = transColor;
  Color testColor = transColor;
  Color right = correctColor;
  Color wrong = redColor;
  Map<int, Color> btnColor = {
    0: Colors.transparent,
    1: Colors.transparent,
    2: Colors.transparent,
  };
  Map<int, Color> tabTextColor = {
    0: Colors.blue[800],
    1: Colors.blue[800],
    2: Colors.blue[800],
  };

  int questionIndex;
  bool disableButton = false;
  bool firstPress = true;
```

This is my Function for checking the correct answer:

```
void checkAnswer1(k) {
      if (questionBank[questionIndex]['answers'][k]['correct']) {
        colorToShow = right;
        Provider.of<QuizData>(context, listen: false).countMarks();
      } else {
        colorToShow = wrong;
        if (questionBank[questionIndex]['answers'][k + 1]['correct']) {
          testColor = right;
        }

        Provider.of<QuizData>(context, listen: false)
            .addWrongAnswers(questionIndex);
        print(Provider.of<QuizData>(context, listen: false).wrongAnswers);
      }
      setState(() {
        tabTextColor[k] = Colors.white;
        btnColor[k] = colorToShow;
        btnColor[k + 1] = testColor;

        disableButton = true;
        firstPress = false;
      });
    }
```

And here are the buttons with their inputs.

```
                                      AnswerTab(
                                          questionBank[questionIndex]['answers']
                                              [0]['text'],
                                          firstPress
                                              ? () => checkAnswer1(0)
                                              : null,
                                          tabTextColor[0],
                                          btnColor[0]),
                                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                                      AnswerTab(
                                          questionBank[questionIndex]['answers']
                                              [1]['text'],
                                          firstPress
                                              ? () => checkAnswer1(1)
                                              : null,
                                          tabTextColor[1],
                                          btnColor[1]),
                                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                                      AnswerTab(
                                          questionBank[questionIndex]['answers']
                                              [2]['text'],
                                          firstPress
                                              ? () => checkAnswer1(2)
                                              : null,
                                          tabTextColor[2],
                                          btnColor[2]),
```

Here is a snippet of my Question Bank

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questionBank = [
  {
    'questionText':
        "Το ψαροντουφεκο στη περιοχή του Κεντρικού Λιμεναρχείου Πειραιά απαγορεύεται:",
    'answers': [
      {'text': "Έξω από το λιμάνι του Πειραιά.", "correct": false},
      {'text': "Στις πλάζ του Πειραιά.", "correct": false},
      {
        'text': "Από την Πειραϊκή Χερσόνησο κι έως το 42 χιλ. Πειραιά Σουνίου.",
        "correct": true
      },
    ]
  },
```

I understand that my problem lies in the Function and the If statements but I can not figure a way.
Right now I have tested to check if only the next button (k+1) is correct to turn green, which it does when I chose a wrong answer, but when I chose a correct one it also turns green.

Please help!

Comment: What is `testColor`?

Comment: Just a second Color variable that I use on the second button. (next button after the one selected -> k + 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create a class for storing question and answers (this helps you in entities management):

```dart
class Qeustion {
  final String text;
  final List<Answer> answers;

  Question(this.text, this.answers);

  factory Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Question(
      json['questionText'],
      json['answers'].map((answer) => Answer.fromJson(answer)),
    );
  }
}

class Answer {
  final String text;
  final bool isCorrect;

  Answer(this.text, this.isCorrect);

  factory Answer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Answer(
      json['text'],
      json['correct'],
    );
  }
}
```

Handle it in UI:

```dart
answers.map((answer) {
  return AnswerTab(
    question.text,
    firstPress ? () => checkAnswer(answer) : null,
    firstPress ? Colors.blue[800] : answer.isCorrect ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
    Colors.transparent,
  ),
});
```

And `checkAnswer`:

```dart
void checkAnswer(Answer answer) {
  if (answer.isCorrect) {
    Provider.of<QuizData>(context, listen: false).countMarks();
  } else {
    Provider.of<QuizData>(context, listen: false).addWrongAnswers(questionIndex);
  }
  setState(() {
    disableButton = true;
    firstPress = false;
  });
}
```

When you are calling `checkAnswer` method you are updated your data in Provider and calling `setState`. `setState` triggers rebuild with new values in `firstPress` and `disableButton`. If `firstPress` is true - `AnswerTab` widget applying it and colorizing tabs with needed color (for correct answer is green, for other - red).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Will try it tomorrow morning. You suggested to make a class for Question and one for Answer and then you use Json in there. I do not have a json file but a list with maps as mentioned above. Do I have to change anything? Also they way you have the ternary operator in the AnswerTab I understand that each button display a colour either green or red. Is that correct? What I wish is, when wrong answered is clicked then only the correct one is displayed green. Thank you again for your massive. help!

Comment: You can format your question and answers from a map from memory (it is JSON format). It is a clean and simple approach to manage entities in the future. After user click on an answer, you change class variable and rebuild the state and answer items rebuilds with new parameters (variable changes).

Comment: Thank you once again! I have never worked with json before and trying to figure everything out. One question please, in the UI, the answers.map((answer) , I get an error at the question.text and the answers.map. I have created the Classes you mentioned in a separate file and imported that file. Any ideas please? :) :) Thank you!

Comment: I think that the problem occurs that the Question and Answer Classes are located in another file and that the variable answers and question.text do not exist in the ui file.

Comment: You can pass a variable with questions and answers to file with UI or create a global variable with it.

Comment: Would there be any possibility to add a delay to the other buttons that are not clicked? so that the button colour that changes will have a delay of 1 second lets say?

Comment: You can do it with `Timer` class.

Comment: Yes thank you, but can it be inserted here some how? firstPress ? Colors.blue[800] : answer.isCorrect ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
    Colors.transparent,